# Why does it overwritten data instead of adding more data in firebase?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I really want to know why the data is overwritten when the user types new data, 
I want it to add more data to it not overwrite it the data
Also want to know how to read it 
Thank you in advance

```
 let oDB = Database.database().reference().child("Data")
    let oDictionary = ["Data1" : strange.text! , "Data2" : stranger.text!]
    let uid = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid
    oDB.child(uid!).setValue(oDictionary) {

        (error, reference) in
        if error != nil{
            print(error!)
        } else  {
            print("saved Sucessfully")
            self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)

        }
    }

 //In another ViewController
 func updateRequest() {
    let uid = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid
    let yDb = Database.database().reference().child("Data").child(uid!)
    postDb.observeSingleEvent(of: .value) { (snapShot) in
        if let snapShotValue = snapShot.value as? Dictionary<String, String> {

        let text = snapShotValue["Data1"]!
        let case = snapShotValue["Data2"]!


        let data = Data()
        data.s= text
        data.y = case

        self.array.append(data)
        self.table.reloadData()
    }
    }
}
```

Comment: Here is the Json : "Data" : {
    "Rxv0p21nhxZZhQhHTjL3KZ0ZDxn1" : {
      "Data1" : "Hil",
      "Data2" : "Hello"
    }
  }

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`setValue` overwrites the old content , You may need `childByAutoId`

```
oDB.child(uid!).childByAutoId().setValue(oDictionary) {

    (error, reference) in
    if error != nil{
        print(error!)
    } else  {
        print("saved Sucessfully")
        self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)

    }
```

This will give this structure

```
Data 
  > uid
    > someKey1             <<<< auto generated 
        Data1:"---"
        Data2:"---"
    > someKey2             <<<< auto generated 
        Data1:"---"
        Data2:"---"
```

---

Read

```
 //In another ViewController
 func updateRequest() {
    let uid = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid
    let yDb = Database.database().reference().child("Data").child(uid!)
    postDb.observeSingleEvent(of: .value) { (snapShot) in
        if let snapShotValue = snapShot.value as? [String:[String:String]] {

          Array(snapShotValue.values).forEach {
            let data = Data()
            data.s= $0["Data1"]!
            data.y = $0["Data2"]! 
            self.array.append(data)
         }

        self.table.reloadData()
    }
    }
}
```

Comment: okay how about reading it too I forgot to say will edit it right now

Comment: Data() is a class that are string of s and string of y does it affect it any other way

Comment: the option in answer and the other with `Codable` no other way

Comment: okay sounds good, i put in my Xcode and it doesn't display the data why is it?

Comment: Hi what if i would like to add a deeper step meaning add another key value pair inside the someKey1?